# Trouble inserting things into an array in assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm

I'm currently trying to learn Assembly, and one of the tasks I am given is to take user input integers and insert those numbers into an array. Once the array has 7 integers, I will loop through the array and print out the numbers. However, I'm currently stuck on how to insert the numbers into the array. Here is the code I have right now:

```
.DATA

inputIntMessage BYTE "Enter an integer: ", 0
inputStringMessage BYTE "Enter a string: ", 0


intArray DWORD 0,0,0,0,0,0,0
intCounter DWORD 0
user_input DWORD ?

.CODE

main PROC

mov eax, intCounter
mov edx, 0

top: 
    cmp eax, 7      
    je final1
    jl L1

L1: intInput inputIntMessage, user_input
    mov ebx, user_input
    mov intArray[edx], ebx ;This is where I think the problem is.
    add edx, 4
    inc eax
    jmp top

final1:

mov ecx, 0
mov edx, 0
printarrayloop: 
            cmp edx,7
            jl L2
            je next
L2: intOutput intArray[ecx] 
    add ecx, 4
    inc edx
next:
```

`next:` just goes to the next problem; irrelevant to this inserting into an array problem. My thinking is that I should use the offset of the array, so I can access the address of each element in the array and directly change that, but I do not know how. Can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: When I run the program the window prompts the user to enter an integer 7 times (which is as intended), and then prints out the first number the user entered. However, the window should be printing out all of the numbers the user entered.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger to watch what happens?

Comment: What's the point of `jl L1; L1:`? Does the `intInput` macro preserve what's in `eax`?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I could not get any information out of it. All of the variables are incrementing correctly, all the registers are what they should be.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Actually, I just noticed an error. jl L1 is supposed to jump to L1 if eax is less than 7 (ie. the code has not yet executed 7 times, so it will continue to execute until it's ran 7 times.) What do you mean by macro preserve what's in `eax`?

Comment: What happens when you do run your program? `jl L1` L1: mov...` does nothing just remove the `jl L1`. `jl L2` `je next` can be reduce to `jge next` . Rather than doing `intArraty[edx]` and then `add edx, 4` you can drop the `add edx,4` and use scaling index addressing by changing `intArray[edx]` to `intArray[edx*4]` (similar thing aplies to your output). Those changes won't fix the bug but will make the code a bit cleaner.

Comment: @MichaelPetch When I run the program the window prompts the user to enter an integer 7 times (which is as intended), and then prints out the first number the user entered.

Comment: You should put that info in your question so that we know what output you do get, and then explain what is suppose to happen.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Roger that. I have updated the question to include that information, and will keep this in mind for future questions.

Comment: One of the issues I do have is that it is unclear what `intInput inputIntMessage, user_input` does (and how it affects registers). Is intInput a macro available to you for your course work? Are there instructions for it? Does it destroy contents of registers?

Comment: @MichaelPetch `intInput` is what we've been using for our work to prompt a message and store the user input into a variable. We have not been shown the underlying code for that, so I apologize for not being able to show it here

Comment: So my understanding is that when you run this - it does allow you to enter all 7 numbers, and then it only prints the first one entered onto the screen?

Comment: @MichaelPetch That is exactly what happens, yes.

Comment: When displaying the numbers - after `inc dx` you don't do a `jmp printarrayloop` to continue the loop. So it just continues onto `next` which in effect only prints one number. Place `jmp printarrayloop` right after `inc dx` and see what happens.

Comment: @MichaelPetch ...Oh my god I cannot believe I didn't catch that hahaha! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary reason why your code only prints one number is because the code that displays the array of numbers does this:

```
mov ecx, 0
mov edx, 0
printarrayloop: 
    cmp edx,7
    jl L2
    je next
L2: intOutput intArray[ecx] 
    add ecx, 4
    inc edx
next:
```

What is missing is that you do not continue the loop after displaying the first number. You need to jump back to *printarrayloop* to process the next number. Add this right below `inc edx`:

```
     jmp printarrayloop
```

There are some other things you may wish to consider. In this code:

```
top: 
    cmp eax, 7      
    je final1
    jl L1

L1: intInput inputIntMessage, user_input
[snip]
final1:
```

You do `cmp eax, 7`. If it is equal you jump out. If it is less then you just branch to label `L1` anyway. You can modify that code by removing the extraneous `jl L1` branch and label. So you would have this:

```
top: 
    cmp eax, 7      
    je final1    
    intInput inputIntMessage, user_input
```

In this code there are some extra instructions that can be removed:

```
mov ecx, 0
mov edx, 0
printarrayloop: 
    cmp edx,7
    jl L2
    je next
L2: intOutput intArray[ecx] 
    add ecx, 4
    inc edx
    jmp printarrayloop
next:
```

Similar to the previous comment I made to compare *EDX* to 7 using `cmp edx,7`. You can simply say that after comparing if it is equal to 7 then you jump out of the loop to `next` . If it is less than 7 it will just continue and print the number out. So your code could look like this:

```
mov ecx, 0
mov edx, 0
printarrayloop: 
    cmp edx,7
    je next
    intOutput intArray[ecx] 
    add ecx, 4
    inc edx
    jmp printarrayloop
next:
```

x86 32-bit code has a scaled addressing mode (with displacement). You can find all the addressing modes described in this summary [here](https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall10/V22.0201-002/addressing_modes.pdf) and more detailed description [here](http://simon.baymoo.org/universe/tools/symset/symset.txt).

You can using a scaling factor (multiply a register by 1,2,4, or 8) when doing addressing. You have code that looks like this:

```
    mov intArray[edx], ebx 
    add edx, 4
```

*EDX* points to the element number you wish to display, multiplying it by 4 will account for the fact that the size of a *DWORD* is 4 bytes. So you can remove the `add edx, 4`and change the code accessing the array to:

```
    mov intArray[edx*4], ebx
```

`intArray[edx*4]` is an address that is equivalent to `intArray+(edx*4)`

You can make a similar change when you output. Delete this line:

```
    add ecx, 4
```

And use scaled addressing with:

```
    intOutput intArray[ecx*4]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Answer is extensive!